# What causes this warning on Safari? "This webpage is using significant energy. Closing it may improve the responsiveness of your Mac"

Tags: reactjs, performance, safari

We have a React website running with lots of high-quality images that has been experiencing this warning. How do you begin debugging this warning message on Safari? Is there specific things that cause this?

[image: Safari warning]

Comment: What is the size of those images and how are they loaded in the app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This message is caused by Safari watchdog process that monitors the Javascript scripts running on a page.  It is there to notify the user when a script is utilizing too many resources. Your page when loaded on my computer raises the CPU utilization to 68 percent. Be weary of loops and custom render code.

Notes for improvement:

- Make the rendering code as efficient as possible.
- Combine the your internal Javascript files into a single file, instead of 7 files. Major improvement.
- When possible(due to licensing and update considerations) include the 9 external scripts into the single file stated above. Minor improvement.
- Split the main page into different sections either as separate pages or dynamically loaded using AJAX. Major improvement.
- Avoid svg files.  SVG files require a lot of computing power to rasterize and display. This is the main cause of the 7 second load times. Convert the files to png at the largest expected display resolution and offer an expanded SVG file if more detail is wanted(by click or delayed mouse over). Major improvement.

The number of images is not the issue.  It is the number of SVG images(on load) and the scripts causing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Open the page in Chrome, open the Developer Tools and then switch over to the "Performance tab".

Then use the 2nd icon from the left - the one that looks like a "reload" button. Which says "Start profiling and reload page".

You will have a full rundown on what is taking how much. You can see in the top what is eating up FPS and CPU, and then you can select the timeframes that had especially high load.

In the bottom part then select the "Call Tree" or "Bottom-Up" tabs, to get a rundown of which scripts and function calls cause performance issues.

Usually "normal" websites ( e.g. not games ) would not have a lot of frame redraws. You can then spot for example if loading spinners are animated with javascript, instead of transforms and transitions; and sometimes they're still re-rendering although they are out of reach.

On a React specific note : It might also make sense to inspect it additionally with the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en). E.g. you might be able to spot if sub-frames are re-rendering constantly for no reason.